# Is it possible to set value of variable from java file?

Tags: android, xml, variables, android-databinding

Here my xml layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="clickHandler"          
            type="com.myproject.android.customer.ui.adapter.MyHandler" />
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.Merchant" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/preview_image_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"
            android:onClick="clickHandler.onClickImageViewFavorite()"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

OK. It's work fine.
Questions:

1. Is it possible to set value of variable **test_variable** in xml from java file?
2. Set value of this variable to  **android:layout_width** ?

Somithing like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
        <variable name="test_variable"  type="Integer"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@{test_variable}"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/preview_image_height"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to worry you also can set `height` and `width` of element from `Activity` as follows

```
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: I want to set **height** only in xml file. I wan't' to use java code for this.